# Access a prototype attribute without creating object instance

Tags: javascript, object

```
function someClass(){
}
someClass.prototype.CONST = 'Some Constant.';

console.log( 'with Obj : '+(new someClass).CONST);
console.log( 'without Obj : '+someClass.CONST);
```

first one gives right answer, second returns undefined, 
now, is there any way to access `CONST` without creating object instance,

I am looking for something similar to accessing static attributes of Java Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap, you can access it:

```
console.log(someClass.prototype.CONST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access **all** prototypical members via an object's prototype member, not just variables:

```
// returns a value
someObject.prototype.someMember

// calls the function someFunct()
someObject.prototype.someFunct()
```

If you need to call a method from one object, using another object as the 'calling instance' you can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
// calls functMember using instanceObject as the instance
someObject.prototype.functMember.call(instanceObject, arg1, arg2, ... );

// calls functMember using isntanceObject as the instance, using an array as arguments
someObject.prototype.functMember.call(instanceObject, [arg1, arg2, ...] );
```